# What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values < 00:00:00? i.e. negative timespan to sql server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, timezone-offset

I am trying to store a .Net TimeSpan in SQL server 2014.

EF Code First seems to be suggesting it should be stored as a Time(7) in SQL.

However TimeSpan in .Net can handle negative values.

What is the best way to handle storing -ve .Net TimeSpan in SQL server?

I need offset in time format in sql so that I can convert UTC datetime value stored in db into users timezone.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type that represents time spans. I'd usually recommend using an integral type, measured in whatever units you need for appropriate resolution, e.g. seconds or milliseconds, etc.

Comment: You could just get the total milliseconds out of the timespan and save it as a big int.

Comment: But as to another part of your question - I'd leave the UTC <-> local translation to your presentation layer and leave the database entirely in UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by  @Damien_The_Unbeliever in comment , adding this in answer. 
SQL Server doesn't have a data type that represents time spans you have to use integral type, measured in whatever units you need for appropriate resolution, e.g. seconds or milliseconds, etc.